# Where is my Iphone backup located in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, backup, itunes, iphone

I recently backed up my Iphone using Itunes. After completing a backup I wanted to find the file but can't seem to find it.

Several web searches have said that the file is in:

```
\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup
```

but there is not even a parent directory of:

```
 \Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\
```

In fact there is no Apple or Apple Computer folders anywhere in
`C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\`. I have also searched the contents of

```
 C:\Program Files(x86) 
 C:\Program Files
```

with no Apple data being there.

I did find some Apple directories in:

```
C:\ProgramData
```

, but neither of these directories have any files that relate to the backup.

and finally, I can not even find where Itunes is installed on my machine, as there are no entries in Program Files and there is no option to 'find in explorer' from the Start Menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer, but instead of deleting the question I believe it is best to post an answer for future help requests with this. I found the location at:

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME}\Apple
```

Answer (score 1):

The most recent backup is here:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup

There may be a backup where you pointed to (C:\Users[USERNAME}\Apple) but that is not necessarily the most recent backup. I saw a much older backup in the C:\Users[USERNAME}\Apple folder.

The best source for the most recent backup is as I posted at the top here.

Support for this can be found at

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204215

Backups in Windows 7, 8, or 10
To find a list of your backups, go to \Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\

> Find the Search bar: In Windows 7, click Start.  In Windows 8, click
> the magnifying glass in the upper-right corner. In Windows 10, click
> the Search bar next to the Start button. In the Search bar, enter
> %appdata% or %USERPROFILE% (if you downloaded iTunes from the
> Microsoft Store).